How properly handle error exception in try and catch block?
I have a problem with the flow of error handling. I have a try and catch block, and I need to ensure that the try block contains the logic for what should be executed. Specifically, a ticket should be created. However, the creation of the ticket can fail for two reasons. The first reason is that it cannot find the responder_id, which means either it doesn't exist or it is working with a responder_id that is no longer in the database. In this case, I need to create a new ticket but set the responder_id to null, which I have implemented and it works.
My issue is with throwing errors. I need to ensure that the try-catch block can throw two types of errors. The first one should be thrown if the failure is due to an invalid responder_id, and the second one should be a general error if the ticket creation fails for any other reason. When I throw an exception only in the catch block, the exception is not thrown even though it is clearly dealing with an invalid responder_id.
I've gotten a bit lost and can't figure out how to do it correctly. Could anyone please offer some advice?
This is code
if ($agent = $this->getAgent()) {
                $data["responder_id"] = $agent;
            }

            try {
                $response = FreshdeskService::createTicket($data, $this->getTo(), $attachments);
                $success = $response["success"] ?? false;

                if (!$success) {
                    $error_response = json_decode($response['response'], true);
                    $error_details = $error_response['errors'] ?? [];

                    foreach ($error_details as $error) {
                        if ($error['field'] === 'responder_id') {
                        }
                    }
                    throw new \Exception("Create ticket failed due to invalid responder_id: " . $this->getAgent() . ". Error details: " . json_encode($error_details));

                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $data['responder_id'] = null;
                $response = FreshdeskService::createTicket($data, $this->getTo(), $attachments);
                Log::info($response);
                $success = $response["success"] ?? false;

                if (!$success) {
                    throw new \Exception("Retry ticket creation failed: From: " . $this->getFrom() . ", To: " . $this->getTo() . ", Subject: " . $this->subject . ", Response: " . json_encode($response["response"] ?? []) . ", Data: " . json_encode($data));
                }
                throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());


            }

I hope this post will find someone who can give me some advice about this problem.

How did you know the exception was not thrown? Exceptions can be caught outside, hidden through configuration, or terminated prematurely due to some reasons (timeout/fatal).

Unrelated to your problem, but throw new \Exception($e->getMessage()); is probably not a good idea, as it discards extra details from the exception. If you just want to rethrow the exception for something else to handle, you can just use throw $e;

@shingo I logged it, and I know that ticket was created successfully on the second attempt because of non existing responder_id. So probably I'm handling error in bad way, becase it doesn't throw error exception.

In general if you see the log, the exception should be thrown too. My question is "How did you know the exception was not thrown?" Do you expect to see an error log or something else but not seeing it?
